# $state.go seems not to be working in my Ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have my login screen where I do a Facebook login (this works perfect) and upon success of FB login it should go to another view. I try to achieve this with

```
$state.go("app.start")
```

But its not working. It just stays on the login view. Not sure why my $state.go is not working ...

My controller for the login button:

angular.module('MovieBankUser.controllers', [])

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $state) {

    $scope.loggingIn = false;

    $scope.login = function () {

        if (!$scope.loggingIn) {
            $scope.loggingIn = true;

            LoginService.loginUser().then(function () {
                $scope.loggingIn = false;
                //$window.location.href = "#/app/start"
                $state.go('app.start');
                //console.log("TEST TEST");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Part of my app.js code for the routing:

```
// Routes
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'components/sidebar_menu/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.start', {
    url: '/start',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/start/start.html',
        controller: 'MovieCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.trending', {
    url: '/trending',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/trending/trending.html',
        controller: 'MovieCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.trending-detail', {
    url: '/trending/:id',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/trending/trending_detail.html',
        controller: 'MovieDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            movie: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getMovieById($stateParams.id)
            },
            trailer: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getTrailerById($stateParams.id)
            },
            cast: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getCastCrewInfo($stateParams.id)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.outnow', {
    url: '/outnow',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/out_now/outnow.html',
        controller: 'MovieCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.outnow-detail', {
    url: '/outnow/:id',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/out_now/outnow_detail.html',
        controller: 'MovieDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            movie: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getMovieById($stateParams.id)
            },
            trailer: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getTrailerById($stateParams.id)
            },
            cast: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getCastCrewInfo($stateParams.id)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.comingsoon', {
    url: '/comingsoon',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/coming_soon/comingsoon.html',
        controller: 'MovieCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.comingsoon-detail', {
    url: '/comingsoon/:id',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/coming_soon/comingsoon_detail.html',
        controller: 'MovieDetailCtrl',
        resolve: {
            movie: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getMovieById($stateParams.id)
            },
            trailer: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getTrailerById($stateParams.id)
            },
            cast: function($stateParams, MovieService) {
              return MovieService.getCastCrewInfo($stateParams.id)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Comment: Can you show your ui-router config?

Comment: @AndreKreienbring: sure i updated my question

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: it looks ok, do you have any error in the console?
Also have you tried to add templateUrl and controller directly in the state configuration rather than in the views?

Comment: @shershen: no i dont have any errors in my console

Comment: Are you sure the if statement is touched? Because if not that would explain a lot.

Comment: rephrasing @Mikey - if you uncomment do your 'console.log("TEST TEST");'  line - does it print to console "TEST TEST"?

Comment: @shershen: no its not printing "TEST TEST"

Comment: There you go! Route is probably ok. Another check to make sure: remove `$state.go('app.start')`

Comment: @Mikey, so what could be the problem? Because when i hit the login button it is giving me my FB details etc that i am logging

Comment: add an error callback and see what the error says

Comment: @GY22 Well if this line `!$scope.loggingIn` is evaluating to false it will never go to the state or do anything.

Comment: @GY22 when do you want the if path is taken? Just describe it in words

Comment: @Mikey: when the fb call is successful and the user has been authenticated with firebase then the if statement should take

Comment: Can you paste this code: `console.log($scope.loggingIn)` above the if statement and tell us what it says?

Comment: @Mikey: its coming back false

Comment: @Gy22 Ok then your deferred is probably rejected. You should catch the error and see what it says.

Comment: @Mikey: my deferred cannot be rejected because i am successfully pulling in FB data as a logged in user ...

Comment: @GY22 Ok, if you are sure you are logged in properly you should try to debug ui-router. See this blog post. I always use it when I suspect ui router is failing silently http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2015/04/ui-router-debug/